# Refreshing SSAS Cube with XMLA script

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, xmla

I am trying to refresh a SSAS cube running on my local machine, that gets its data from the server.

I have reviewed a few websites such as http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929186.aspx for assistance but it doesnt seem to help.

Below is my script and settings:

server: 127.0.0.1\MSSQLSERVER1

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
<Parallel>
<Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100">
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>db </DatabaseID>
    <CubeID>cube_name</CubeID>
  </Object>
  <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
  <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
</Process>
</Parallel>
</Batch>
```

it keeps throwing out an error of:

11/25/2013 08:34:57,process dailer cube job,Error,1,KARABOV-HP\MSSQLSERVER1,process dailer cube job,process cube,,Executed as user: NT Service\SQLAgent$MSSQLSERVER1.  or the object does not exist." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" />.  The step failed.,00:00:00,0,0,,,,0

Please assist.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the script - executed from an XMLA window in Management Studio - run successfully, or do you get an error message there, which may be slightly more readable?

Comment: @FrankPl here is the output:  
<return xmlns="urn:Schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
  <results xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/xmla-multipleresults">
    <root xmlns="urn:Schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:empty" />
  </results>
</return>
successfully Executed
The cubeupdated

Comment: So the script itself runs without producing an error. Then I would assume an issue with the user executing it. Probably, the user that you configured the Integration Services step to "run as" (`NT Service\SQLAgent$MSSQLSERVER1` according to the error message) does not have the right to process the cube.

Comment: @FrankPl, that would appear to make more sense now, so what i have done is added the script to a stored procedure and getting that to run every 30min. I will try to sort out the user rights so long.

Answer (score 0):

Is it executing as the built-in SQL agent account?  I doubt this account has admin permissions on SSAS (nor should it!). I recently had to configure scheduled, remote processing and these 2 links worked for me:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178142.aspx, and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929186.aspx